# How to retry an API call in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern for my Android app. Everything looks so good. But when a network error occur, I need to show a popup message with a Retry button which is expected to call that API again. The problem is when the Retry button is clicked, it doesn't know which API returned that error to retry. Can someone give me an advise?

```
/**
 * Created by Nguyen on 3/27/2019.
 *
 * This BaseFragment will contain the common functions which can be shared in all fragments.
 * All of the fragments in the app should be extended from this class
 */
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

    ...

    protected fun registerViewModel(viewModel: BaseViewModel) {

        ...

        viewModel.noNetworkErrorMessage().observe(this, Observer {
            it.consume {

                // I can add a listener here to handle when the Retry 
                // button is clicked
                DialogHelper.showNoInternetConnectionDialog(context) 
            }
        })

        ...

        viewModel.timedOutMessage().observe(this, Observer {
            it.consume {
                DialogHelper.showAutoDismissErrorPopup(
                    context,
                    getString(R.string.error_request_time_out) {
                        // When the retry button is clicked
                    }
                )
            }
        })
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Retrofit` you will get the raw request from error method. So In your view model`s method you can pass the url.

So the scenario will be:

```
YourViewModel extends ViewModel{
  MutableLiveData<String> url;
  .....
  MutableLiveData<String> timedOutMessage(){
    return url;
}

}
```

So when network error or timeout error occurred send the url to view for retry .

I think you will get the basic idea.

Comment: do you mean in the view, we will check the parameters of the URL, then we can know which method of the viewmodel was called before, then we can call that method again?

Comment: In your base Fragment you receive network error or other error. Now think about your mainFragment who extend BaseFragment. Suppose you have mainViewModel and in this mainViewModel you have a method onError() who take response from **onFailure** from retrofit . Then from **onFailure** return the url in onError. SO you can access onError from you baseFragment and you can use url

Comment: Thanks Tariqul, 
I got your idea. But is there a way we can map the url with the appropriate method of the view model? 
Because there are some actions require multiple API calls to process, if we only retry the failure URL, it doesn't retry the whole process.